# Eslint: How to use globally installed eslint-plugin-vue

Tags: node.js, vue.js, eslint, eslint-plugin-vue

I would like to use linter **elint-plugin-vue** as *global* installation since i use Docker a lot and i might not have a `node_modules` folder at the root of my repositories.
Previously, i have installed the linter like this: `sudo npm install -g eslint eslint-plugin-vue vue-eslint-parser`

However, when running `/usr/bin/eslint --ext .vue Footer.vue` in absence of any `node_modules` folder, i get the following:

```
Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 7.23.0

ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-vue".

(The package "eslint-plugin-vue" was not found when loaded as a Node module from the directory "/home/user".)

It's likely that the plugin isn't installed correctly. Try reinstalling by running the following:

    npm install eslint-plugin-vue@latest --save-dev

The plugin "eslint-plugin-vue" was referenced from the config file in "PersonalConfig".

If you still can't figure out the problem, please stop by https://eslint.org/chat/help to chat with the team.
```

`ls -la /usr/lib/node_modules/ | grep lint` shows:

```
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root   4096 30. Mär 18:56 eslint
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root   4096 30. Mär 18:56 eslint-plugin-vue
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root   4096 19. Mär 23:09 jsonlint
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   4096 30. Mär 21:43 vue-eslint-parser
```

`~/.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended"
  ]
}
```

The above error pops up as soon as i put `"plugin:vue/vue3-recommended"` inside `~/.eslintrc`.
Is there a way to make this work? Would be great to have this as fallback if the repository i'm working with has no `node_modules` locally.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `--resolve-plugins-relative-to` flag to change the directory where plugins are resolved from.

For example, in your case:

```bash
eslint . --resolve-plugins-relative-to=/usr/lib/
```

or you can try getting the path dynamically

```bash
# Yarn
eslint . --resolve-plugins-relative-to=$(yarn global dir)

# npm
eslint . --resolve-plugins-relative-to=$(npm root -g)
```